# javascript "prompt is not defined" Reference Error

Tags: javascript

```
(function() {
    var random_num = Math.floor(Math.random()*10) + 1;
    var input_num = prompt("Guess the number between 1 and 10");
    if (input_num < 1 || input_num > 10) {
        alert('the input number is not between 1 and 10');

    } else if (random_num == input_num) {
        alert('Good Work');
    } else {
        alert('Not matched, the random number is: ' + random_num);
    }

})();
```

But the IDE displays that "prompt" is not defined. Could someone help me explain why?

Comment: That depends on the IDE. It works https://jsfiddle.net/L364hf7v/

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: prompt is a `window` property function. If `window` is not in the context of a browser, as @adeneo said, `prompt` cannot exist.

Comment: @SterlingArcher My IDE is webstorm, and I also used window, and it still didn't work.

Comment: if you write ``window.prompt()``, it should be recognized.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using JSHint in WebStorm,  set Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Code Quality Tools > JSHint > Environments > Browser to true

[Screenshot of WebStorm settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFiag.png)

Update: 
Also, as mentioned earlier, for good code you should use `window.prompt`, just so it's clear you're using the built in browser prompt rather than a custom function etc... (the same goes for alert, so use `window.alert`)

Finally, unrelated to the question, but something I noticed - it's good practice to use the `===` operator. There are a million articles online explaining why :)

Comment: Thanks! `window.prompt` was the solution for me